# this.setState remains false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components `CardDeck` and `Card`

CardDeck

```
export default class CardDeck extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    addCards(cards, input, cardType) {
        cards.push(<Card cardType="10" cardNum={1} key = {11} pressed = {false} onCardClicked = {this.selectCard.bind(this)}/>);

        }       
    }

    selectCard(card, callback) {
        this.forceUpdate();
        callback();

    }

    render() {
        var cards = [];

        cards.push(<Card cardType="10" cardNum={1} key = {11} pressed = {false} onCardClicked = {this.selectCard.bind(this)}/>);

        return (<div>
            {cards}
        </div>);
    }
}
```

Card Component

```
export default class Card extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            "clicked": this.props.pressed
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.props = nextProps;
        this.setState({
            clicked: this.props.pressed
        });
    }

    onClick(e) {
        this.props.onCardClicked({
            cardType: this.props.cardType,
            cardNum: this.props.cardNum
        }, () => {
            this.setState((state, props) => {
                var newState =  {
                    "clicked": !(state.clicked)
                };
                return newState;
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        var clickedButtonStyle = {
            "borderStyle": "inset"
        };

        var normalButtonStyle = {
            "borderStyle": "outset"
        };

        return <span><button style = {this.state.clicked ? clickedButtonStyle : normalButtonStyle} onClick = {this.onClick.bind(this)}><img comment = "The card image gets picked"/></button></span>;
    }
}
```

The logic I have implemented is that if a card is clicked, it is shown with `borderStyle:inset`. But at any point of time, only one card can be clicked. If the user clicks on a second card, the first card's `borderStyle` has to be changed to outset and the second card's style has to be inset. So when a card is clicked, it calls the function in the parent `CardDeck` (`selectCard`) which triggers a re render of all the cards to `pressed=false`. Then the callback passed to it gets called which changes the `this.state.clicked` of the card pressed to true.

But for some reason, the re render from the `CardDeck` component is getting bundled with the callback state update and `this.state.clicked` of card pressed remains false.

Can anyone correct me I am doing anything wrong or suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: try commenting the code in `componentWillReceiveProps` and see if you get the right behaviour

Comment: I need that because `this.state.clicked` is getting it's value from `this.props.pressed`.

Comment: i understand that, but does removing tat piece of code gives you desired behaviour after clicking the button ??

Comment: I'm going to say that honestly your code is really "fighting" against React. The entire way you have it structured is a little counter-intuitive. What is the point of `forceUpdate` in this case? Why does the callback need to be passed up to the parent, why not just execute it in `onClick`, since it only affects child state? Either the `Card` should be in charge of it's own state entirely, or it should be completely "dumb", with `CardDeck` controlling everything about the child Card's state. Because right now, `CardDeck` is just rendering the exact same card over and over.

Comment: To add to Amleonard's comment, you are treating React components as objects, calling functions on them to make things happen, when the correct way to use React components (not objects in general, but specifically React components) is to specify changes to them through component properties in the parent, and then only generate UI components in render (or its chain). Not "in preparation of render getting called at some point" as you do right now in `addCards()`.

Comment: @Amleonard forceUpdate is needed because the CardDeck should re render all the cards to not clicked (in case any other card was clicked before this). Also the callback needs to be passed to the parent because once it has made all the `Cards` to not clicked mode, callback will make the card clicked to clicked mode. I agree that the Card has to be completely dumb about it being active. I'll change the structure moving the state to parent.

Comment: @yaswanth I believe that refactoring it in that way will make it a lot easier to reason about, and for you to see exactly how it's working. You might be able to solve your own problem by taking that more idiomatic approach. But post an update here if you still have trouble after that change.

Comment: i believe you can save more resources by adding a variable to your deck which has the ID of card that has the inset or clicked state. that way you dont have to rerender them all but you will just have to negate the state of that card. also it would be much easier if your data is an object. and map it to a component, rather than pushing a component into your array. hope this helps.